# (401 Authorization Required) on Twitter API request

Tags: angularjs, twitter, jsonp, http-status-code-403, http-status-code-401

I'm trying to do a simple request to Twitter API using AngularJS, based on [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRelx4-ISbs) and I get this error:

```
"GET http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=angular.callbacks._0&q=angularjs 401 (Authorization Required)"
```

code:

```
$scope.twitter = $resource('http://search.twitter.com/:action',
    {action:'search.json', q: 'angularjs', callback:'JSON_CALLBACK'},
    {get:{method:'JSONP'}}
);
```

Does it relate to the following statement (taken from [Twitter API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses))?

> 401 - Unauhtorized - (...) Also returned in other circumstances, for example all calls to API v1
>   endpoints now return 401 (use API v1.1 instead).

Why do I get this error? By using `http://search.twitter.com` as the resource, does that mean I'm using the most recent API (v1.1)? Can I choose which API i'm accessing? How?

If I use `http://api.twitter.com` as the resource, I get a 403 error instead:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`

which, according to the [Twitter API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses), implies that

`(...) This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits.`

which does not make sense, because I tried that only a couple dozen times... I'm confused.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi i just finished integrating the Twitter API myself, this is how i did it:

1. Create an app on twitter
2. Download twitteroauth PHP SDK from [HERE](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth)
3. Create a file named twitter.php with the following code:

**twitter.php:**

```
include_once "lib/twitteroauth.php";

class Twitter {
    private $consumerKey = "YourConsumerKey";
    private $consumerSecret = "YourConsumerSecret";
    private $token = "AppToken";
    private $tokenSecret = "AppTokenSecret";

    function __construct() {
        if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
            $this->getTweets($_GET['page']);
        }
    }
    //In my case i just wanted to get Tweets
    private function getTweets ($page) {
        $connection = $this->getConnectionWithAccessToken();
        echo json_encode($connection->get("statuses/user_timeline", array("count" => 5, "page" => $page)));
    }

    private function getConnectionWithAccessToken() {
        return new TwitterOAuth($this->consumerKey, $this->consumerSecret, $this->token, $this->tokenSecret);
    }
}
$twitter = new Twitter();
```

**Angular Service/Factory:**

```
var url = "http://yourwebsite.com/twitter.php";
var page = 1;
$http.get(url, {
        params: {
            page : page //Optional params, but necesary for the example to work
        }
    })
    .success(function (response) {
        //Do something with the response
        page++;
    });
```

And that's it, just add your private date such as consumerKey and Token and it will work (in this example a call to the API to get some tweets). For other API commands refferance to the API documentation from twitter which you can find [HERE](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1)

Goodluck

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that soon - right now I'm kind of suffering from sleep deprivation and I'm just leaving work. However, taking a brief look at your answer, is that all really necessary for realizing a simple API request? Cheers

Comment: Alright, let me know if you have any questions. Yep that is all

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is helpful but Twitter has an awesome tool to explore the twiiter API even before you start writing code. [Twitter Console](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console). Apparently doing a rough search on the console will show you that Authorization is required. As a plus it shows you the response from the Twitter API for your query and more. This can be very helpful if you want specific details as was in my case.